# function as argument in fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

For an academic paper, the authors have provided their code of their results and so I am trying to run their code. When I compile, there is an error which says that a function cannot be used as an argument. Here below I provide the relevant parts of the code that the error seem to point out (In particular the message is: `"error 997 - An internal FUNCTION, such as FOC, cannot be used as an actual argument"`).

.........

```
 function foc(ain)
    implicit none
    real*8:: ain, foc

    foc =  plterm+meru(ain,i)-upap(n,ain,i)
  end function foc
```

...........

```
  yy1 = zbrent(foc,a(np-1),yexp,errrel)
```

where zbrent is a subroutine called by the main program. If necessary I can attach the whole code.

```
FUNCTION zbrent (func,x1,x2,tol)
  implicit none
  real(8), external:: func
  real(8), intent(in):: x1,x2,tol

END FUNCTION zbrent
```

I am not familiar with Fortran or any programming and wondering whether someone can advice something.

Comment: What it says exactly? Copy here the important information so we don't have to guess. How is `zbrent` defined?

Comment: @VladimirF I have updated the post with the relevant information you asked. The error message says exactly what I have in the post: error 997 - An internal FUNCTION, such as FOC, cannot be used as an actual argument". Hope now is more clear, if not shall I post the whole code ?

Comment: OK, I missed the error message in your post.

Comment: I managed to fix bug by writting the module you suggested, however now when i execute the code this error shows up:

Comment: @VladimirF please see the screen shot in the original

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in the error message:

```
An internal FUNCTION, such as FOC, cannot be used as an actual argument
```

Your function `foc` is apparently an internal function. It is placed after the word `contains` in the main program or in another procedure.

Internal procedures are prohibited to be a passed as argument in Fortran 2003 and earlier. Fortran 2008 relaxed this.

Place the function in a module and it will be OK. Also external one will work in this case, but I do not recommend it that much (that means just move `foc` outside of everything).

Or use a compiler that implements the Fortran 2008 rules for this (recent versions of gfortran should suffice).

Comment: For someone one doesn't know programming, the solution of upgrading the compiler might be easiest.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion I commented in a different section. I fixed this particular bug, but now upon execution a new error shows up. I tried to provide a screen shot, but the site here does not allow me as i do not have the necessary reputation points. The error basically says the following :

Comment: Salford. Fortran. RuntimeException error 128: file does not exists and the details of this file. My confusion is that what the error says the file does not exists is a particular file that is created withing a subroutine of that the main program calls.

Comment: If it compiles now youhave a different error. Start a new question